# Resize image in OpenCv python, filling space with color

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

i'm trying to resize an image to a default value, filling the entire space.
I've tried to create a blank background, pasting the image i have but i'm having errors:

```
# image_toresize it's the image I want to apply over the background
# the image im using for the background
blank_image = np.zeros((600,900,3), np.uint8)
blank_image = (255,255,255)

l_img = blank_image.copy()
x_offset = y_offset = 0
height, width = image_toresize.shape[:2]

l_img[0:height, 0:width] = image_toresize.copy()
```

> this error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (90,657) into shape (90,657,3)
```

What can i do?

Comment: What is `blank_image` and `image_toresize`? Please post full code.

Comment: blank image it's the background, image_toresize it's the one i want to put over he background

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
image_toresize = cv2.imread('flower5.jpg')     
height, width = image_toresize.shape[:2]

blank_image = np.zeros((600,900,3), np.uint8)
blank_image[:,:] = (255,255,255)

l_img = blank_image.copy()                    # (600, 900, 3)

x_offset = y_offset = 100
# Here, y_offset+height <= blank_image.shape[0] and x_offset+width <= blank_image.shape[1]
l_img[y_offset:y_offset+height, x_offset:x_offset+width] = image_toresize.copy()

cv2.imshow('img', l_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

**Figure 1**: Original Image

[image]

**Figure 2**: Above image added to a white empty background

[image]

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (78,45) into shape (78,45,3)

Comment: Here, `y_offset+height <= blank_image.shape[0]` and `x_offset+width <= blank_image.shape[1]`

Comment: BTW, your are converting your image to grayscale. Here, input image is color with 3 channels. Change it in your case.

Comment: If you want to use above code for grayscale image, then use this: `blank_image = np.zeros((600,900), np.uint8)
blank_image[:,:] = (255)`